# How to send a considerably large file of any format from express NodeJS server to Django server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, django, multer

I have written this code to send a file using a port from NodeJS server to Django server using multer and Custom Directives from AngularJS

```
const multerConf = {
    storage:multer.diskStorage({
        filename:function(req,file,next){
            const etx = file.mimeType.split('/')[1];
            next(null,file,fieldname+'-'+Date.now()+'-'+ext);
        }
    })
};
var newName = '';
app.post('/upload', multer(multerConf).single('file'), function(req, res){
    if(req.files.file){
        req.body.file = req.files.filename;
        var file = req.files.file;
        var filename = req.files.file.name;
        newName = './upload/'+Date.now()+filename;
        file.mv(newName,function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.send("Upload failed");              
            }else{
                var fileUrl='./upload/'+filename;
                console.log(fileUrl);
            }
        });

    const options = {  
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/myAssignmentApp/a_n_d',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8'
        }
    };
    request(options, function(err, res) {  
    });
}
});
```

The following code is for the port.

```
server.on('request', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(newName, (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
        res.end(data);
    });
});
server.listen(6000);
```

Is there any other more efficient method to do the same?